Woman and her boy struggle to survive after leaving their family
I watched this movie I'm about to tell you about 2 years ago, But I only saw half of it, mostly the end. It's and independent film, no one that I could recognize, and it was maybe from Lebanon, Israel, Iran, or Romania - I don't really know -, but it wasn't American or in English.
It was about a girl named Una (maybe). I have vague memories, she goes to live whith some guy but in the apartment where his family lives as well. And in that culture the woman can't do a lot of this or be free, and her in-laws were always watching. Her husband hits her once and pretty badly and she decides to leave him.
So one night she grabs her things and their child who was a little boy and runs away to this kind of refuge for domestic violence women and starts to live in there and finds a job. I think she falls again for another man and they start to live together. She looks for a job and they have a bed in that place.
One day she goes walking down the street with her son, and someone runs and takes him from her hand and they put him in a cab. She runs behind that guy and it turns out to be her brother and her parents were at the car, waiting. They say that what was she expecting that the father had rights to see the little boy and she was an embarrassment to the family and that they still support her husband, that she should come back and just accpet her life. She recovers her son and runs away from them, but at the end of the movie she goes walking with her child and someone comes walking fast behind her and she holds the boy in her arms and turns over, and when she turns her brother kills her son whith a knive. She saw that it was her brother, he was the best friend of her ex husband. She lies in the street with her child while he dies in her arms, the brother gets into a bus after stabbing his nephew...
So please if someone saw this super dramatic movie, please help me with the name. I recall something like Una or Sola but couldn't find it, like that.

Welcome to the community. I hope you like it here.
